# Disable web login in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

Working in a home LAN, no one else is able to reach this development instance. Still, pgAdmin 4 forces a login through its web interface, which is different from the credentials used to login to the actual Postgres service. In a development environment this is just a nuisance, two different logins to connect to a service.

How can I disable the web login in pgAdmin 4?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html):

```
# The server mode determines whether or not we're running on a web server
# requiring user authentication, or desktop mode which uses an automatic
# default login.
#
# DO NOT DISABLE SERVER MODE IF RUNNING ON A WEBSERVER!!
#
# We only set SERVER_MODE if it's not already set. That's to allow the
# runtime to force it to False.
#
# NOTE: If you change the value of SERVER_MODE in an included config file,
#       you may also need to redefine any values below that are derived
#       from it, notably various paths such as LOG_FILE and anything
#       using DATA_DIR.

if (not hasattr(builtins, 'SERVER_MODE')) or builtins.SERVER_MODE is None:
    SERVER_MODE = True
else:
    SERVER_MODE = builtins.SERVER_MODE
```

Try setting `SERVER_MODE` to `False` in the config.py, config_distro.py, config_local.py, or config_system.py.

However, regard this note:

> If the SERVER_MODE setting is changed in config_distro.py,
> config_local.py, or config_system.py you will most likely need to
> re-set the LOG_FILE, SQLITE_PATH, SESSION_DB_PATH and STORAGE_DIR
> values as well as they will have been set based on the default
> configuration or overridden by the runtime.

Comment: I added `SERVER_MODE = False` in line 115 of `config.py` (strange to change a configuration setting directly in a code file). Then restarted the server but the log-in is still required.

Comment: Mabe a builtin brings in SERVER_MODE = True (in line 118) or it gets set in one of the other config files. Maybe try setting it in another file, the correct one seems to be config_local.py: This file is read after config_distro.py and is intended for end users to change any default or packaging specific settings that they may wish to adjust to meet local preferences or standards.This file is optional, and may be created by users in the same directory as config.py if needed.

Comment: There is no file named `config_local.py` in my system.

Comment: Per documentation: This file is optional, and may be created by users in the same directory as config.py if needed.

Comment: After creating the `config_local.py` file and adding `SERVER_MODE=False` the pgAdmin service started returning an HTTP 500 error. I went through the logs and found no culprit, tried restarting both Postgres and Apache, etc, but pgAdmin never came back. I removed it from the system and will stick with `psql` and `dbvis` for the time being.